# SQL How do you SUM the fields retrieved by COUNT?

Tags: sql, sum

This is what I tried, but it didnt work.

```
Select customer_id, sum(count (contact_id), count (call_id))
from contacts
limit 10
```

Comment: `Select customer_id, count (contact_id) + count (call_id)
from contacts
limit 10`

Comment: "Avoid answering questions in comments" - the tooltip text of the "add comment" linkbutton

Comment: Although irrelevant for this question, you should always add a tag for the DBMS you are using (Postgres, Oracle, ...). Sometimes even simple questions turn out to have solutions that depend on the actual DBMS product being used (The tag `sql` only refers to the _query language_ not any specific DBMS product)

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to add together the count of contact_ids and call_ids you can simply use + between the two fields

```
Select customer_id, count (contact_id)+count (call_id)
from contacts
limit 10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select customer_id, count (contact_id) + count (call_id)
from contacts
limit 10
```

you may need a GROUP BY clause unless your db adds one for you (mysql in certain configurations)